# Get most recent value in json dot net core

Tags: json, list, generics, .net-core

I'm getting JSON response something like this...

```
{
    "message": "All Time Score Standing with friends",
    "response": [
        {
            "userId": "123",
            "newId": "321",
            "points": 40
        },
        {
            "userId": "123",
            "newId": "321",
            "points": 60
        },
        {
            "userId": "456",
            "newId": "654",
            "points": 150
        },
        {
            "userId": "456",
            "newId": "654",
            "points": 180
        }
    ]
}
```

So, What I want is, from this list I just want to extract only one data for the respective user (with the most recent value of points). In conclusion, I want to remove redundancy and want to get single data for every user.

**My Expected Result is something like :**

```
{
    "message": "All Time Score Standing with friends",
    "response": [       
        {
            "userId": "123",
            "newId": "321",
            "points": 60
        },
        {
            "userId": "456",
            "newId": "654",
            "points": 180
        }
    ]
}
```

**NOTE** : Response is Generic type in c# which I'm passing

Comment: There's no `Jason` in .NET. Which library are you using? JSON.NET? Or System.Text.Json? Since .NET Core 3.1 System.Text.Json is the default JSON library. You can parse the JSON string with either and retrieve the part you want. What you ask though isn't simple data access, it's a complex operation. You aren't removind redundancy, you're picking an object in an array based on `MAX(points)`. You'll have to deserialize the data into objects, filter the items you want and return them, eg using LINQ

Comment: BTW `"statusCode": 200,` ??????? The status code is an HTTP header, not a JSON field. If the header says 500, 404 or 200, it doesn't matter what the JSON body says.